# How to set maximum pool connection size and idle time for ibm.db2.jcc.db2connectionpool

Tags: database, spring-boot, jdbc, db2, connection-pooling

Hi I am working on a spring boot project where I am using DB2ConnectionPoolDataSource and DB2PooledConnection for connection pooling. I was going through the documentation but couldn't find how to set DB2ConnectionPoolDatasource related maximum pool and idle connections in yaml file. I am setting up tomcat idle time but it is not overriding the connections.Thanks.